# Which data structure (Array or B+ tree) is best for the fowllowing scenario in memory?

Tags: arrays, tree

Which data structure (Array or B+ tree) is best for the fowllowing scenario in memory?

A file is containing sorted numbers (around 1024 numbers in file).

1. we have to put all numbers in a data structure.
2. one search operation.

i know searching an array with binary search is O(log n).but building an array is fast     than B+ tree.
   But dont know about the search operation of B+tree ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching through a B+ tree is of O(log n) as well.
If you just need to search through a list of sorted numbers, then an array would be your best bet, especially if you are not planning to insert/delete numbers from the list.

Comment: but we dont know the actual count of numbers in file.

Comment: @SAHILSINGLA That is ok, you can dynamically reallocate the array, or take a count first and then allocate the array size accordingly.

Comment: one last question......if the numbers are present in disk block instead of a file..then we can count ?.\

Comment: @SAHILSINGLA well yes you could, if you have the correct logic (i'm not sure exactly how to do that though)